# Run a batch after finish printing a file

Tags: batch-file, printing

Here's what I want to do:

When I click print from a program to print a file, I want that run a batch file after the file finishes printing. The batch file is:

```
## Heading ##
## RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "Printer" PortName "USB001" RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "Printer" PortName "Deafult:"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `print` command:

> Print a file or files to a local or network printer.
>
> Syntax
>         PRINT [/D:device] [pathname(s)]
>
> Key    device   : either a local printer (LPTx, COMx )
>                 or a network printer by its sharename (\servername\print_share)
>
> pathname : The file or files to be printed

More info here: http://ss64.com/nt/print.html

Comment: I am sorry, i would like to enter to any program and click the option print. Then when the file has finished printing, i would like that run a batch file automatically which the commands are:
----------
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "Printer" PortName "USB001"
----------
RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "Printer" PortName "Port:"

I will put an example.
I open the program adobe reader, then i open any file, then i click the option File, then the option Print. But when the file is finshed printing, i would like that a batch file is run automatically after that.

Comment: @user3026028 oh! ok, so like a "after print event" ...?

Comment: You can't automate it, unless you use an `AutoIt` script to actually click the print function and then the autoit script can launch the batch file.  Even then the script has no way of knowing when the file has finished printing - you would have to use a fixed delay.